# Autogenerated questionnaire using SO as source

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Today I was thinking about how it's possible to use the great database of SO to produce automated survey. (My idea was for job interviews or to prepare to them).

**The question:**  do you think it could be useful ? if yes, do you think that SO it could be ready or need more tool/features ?

Comment: I'm not sure this is such a good idea. All your candidates would need to know is that Jon Skeet is awesome, and that's perhaps not *quite* enough to be a good employee of your company. (Notwithstanding the fact that it is great as a principle for life, of course.)

Comment: come on, I'm serious, if questions and answers are properly filtered/tagged could be easy create a survey using tags for the topics and question level for the difficulty.